# Node.js / Webstorm: KOA framework - unresolved function / method

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, koa

I am using the node.js KOA framework for setting up a server:

```
var http = require ('http');
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

app.use(function* (){           
  this.body = 'Hello World';
});

var server = http.createServer(app.callback()); 

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
    var address = server.address();
    console.log("Listening on port " + address.port);
});
```

I am using Webstorm for my coding and it generates the following warnings:

> Unresolved method or function use()

and

> Unresolved method or function callback()

in relation to `app.use()` and `app.callback()`. The KOA module is part of my project folder. I suspect the problem has something to do with the fact that the properties on `app` is the following:

```
{subdomainOffset: 2, 
proxy: false, 
env: 'development' }
```

while the methods in question are part of the `app`'s prototype chain:

```
[ Application {
    listen: [Function],
    toJSON: [Function],
    inspect: [Function],
    use: [Function],
    callback: [Function],
    createContext: [Function],
    onerror: [Function] }
```

Is there any way to get Webstorm to resolve `app.use()` and `app.callback()`?

Comment: Thank you, @FlorianLemaitre. It appears to be a duplicate. Too bad the other post does not contain any solution / work around (e.g. via use of JSdoc)